# Разница описаний каскадного удаления в EF 6 и Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Каскадное удаление (автоматическое удаление зависимой сущности после удаления главной) описывается по-разному в EF 6 и EF Core

В EF 6 описание каскада производится на главной сущности:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
.HasMany(p => p.Phones)
.WithRequired(p=>p.Company)
.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

В EF Core описание каскада производится на зависимой сущности:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Phone>()
.HasOne(p => p.Company)
.WithMany(t => t.Phones)
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Непонятно, чем руководствовались разработчики, когда принимали решение сделать в EF core иначе, вероятно они видели преимущество новой схемы? Если да, то какое? Я вот сколько ни обдумывал этот вопрос так и не нашёл какой-то конкретной киллерфичи, да и вообще оба варианта кажутся мне примерно одинаковыми.

Comment: Ну xз, по мне `HasOne.WithMany` выглядит более понятной связью, чем `HasMany.WithRequired`

Comment: Если отталкиваться от реляционной модели, то вариант в EF Core, действительно более логичный, т.к. в SQL внешние ключи и каскады прописывается как раз на зависимых таблицах. Других причин не вижу, по мне так оба варианта далеки от идеала и не слишком читабельны сходу без документации.