# Модель подписчиков и подписок в EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Мне надо сделать что-то типо модели подписок и подписчиков на YouTube. Есть юзер он может иметь подписчиков, так же он может и сам подписываться на юзеров.

```
public class User : BaseId
{
    public string Login { get; set; }   
    public virtual List<Subscription> Subscribers { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Subscriber> Subscription { get; set; }
}

public class Subscription : BaseId
{
    //info about publisher
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    //info about subscriber
    public virtual User Subscriber { get; set; }
    public int? SubscriberId { get; set; }
}

public class Subscriber : BaseId
{
    //info about subscriber
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    // link to subscription -> publisher
    public virtual Subscription Subscription { get; set; }
    public int? SubscriptionId { get; set; }
}
```

Сделал что-то такое, но при такой модели база не создается, вылетает ексепшин`System.InvalidOperationException: "Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Subscription.User' of type 'User'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'."`

Как сделать такую модель правильно ? Чтобы все работало

Comment: Уточните, какую именно версию вы используете: EF 6 или EF Core?

Comment: EF Core Использую

Comment: Вам достаточно хранить в базе одну таблицу (помимо дефолтной Users): на кого подписались.

Comment: Лучше использовать только метку ef core - чтобы отвечающие не путались, а то есть разночтения, скажем: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1012020/213987

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам достаточно хранить в базе одну таблицу (помимо дефолтной Users): на кого подписались.

```
public class User
{
    // Кто подписан на User
    public virtual List<Subscription> MySubscribers  { get; set; }

    // На кого подписан User
    public virtual List<Subscription> MySubscriptions { get; set; }
}

public class Subscription
{
    // Кто подписался
    public int WhoId { get; set; }
    public User Who { get; set; }

    // На кого подписался
    public int ToWhomId { get; set; }
    public User ToWhom { get; set; }
}
```

При этом важно указать связи между сущностями:

```
public class SubscriptionConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Subscription>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Subscription> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(x => x.ToWhom)
               .WithMany(x => x.MySubscribers)
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder.HasOne(x => x.Who)
               .WithMany(x => x.MySubscriptions)
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}
```